# R Setting legends and colours iteratively in a function

Tags: r, ggplot2

TL;DR: Adding lines stepwise to a plot and getting the legend right in ggplot

I have a set of dataframes with identical column names but different values (see example dataframe in the bottom).

Often I need to plot these dataframes on one graph with the standard deviation plotted as a ribbon like so:

```
a = ggplot() + geom_ribbon(data = na.omit(m), aes(x = Time, ymin=SDmin, ymax=SDplus), alpha = 0.5, fill ="grey") +geom_line(data = na.omit(m), aes(x = Time, y = OD_scaled, color = "Growth")) + xlab("Time (H)") + ylab("OD Scaled")
a + geom_ribbon(data = na.omit(p), aes(x = Time, ymin=SDmin, ymax=SDplus), alpha = 0.5, fill ="grey") +geom_line(data = na.omit(p), aes(x = Time, y = OD_scaled, color = "photo")) + xlab("Time (H)") + ylab("OD Scaled")
```

[image: Multiple plot]

I need to do this a lot with different combinations of data (always the same dataframe format) so I was writing a function which can add dataframes to the plot in an additive manner:

```
plot.OD = function(df, Growth, graph_name) {
  if(missing(graph_name)) {
    graph_name = ggplot()
  }

  graph_name = graph_name + geom_ribbon(data = na.omit(df), aes(x = Time, ymin=SDmin, ymax=SDplus), alpha = 0.5, fill ="grey") +geom_line(data = na.omit(df), aes(x = Time, y = OD_scaled, color = Growth)) + xlab("Time (H)") + ylab("OD Scaled")
  return(graph_name)
}
}
```

I then call the function using:

```
a = plot.OD(df1,"Mix")
a
#Adding a plot is done like this:
a +  plot.OD(df2,"Photo",a)
```

This is the result:
[image: Second plot]

As you can see the legend and the colours are not assigned automatically.

So my question: how can I improve this function so the legend will be updated automatically?

Please find two example dataframes at this [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0ByzEtLcd1ATGMTRjSlhwc2VUZXc?usp=sharing) (used the save function to save them)

```
Time R B W T Tprof    Tmeas    Tcool pH OD_scaled SD SDmin SDplus
0.002777778 0 0 0 0    21 21.13767 3.524333  0         2  0     2      2
0.005555556 0 0 0 0    21 21.12400 3.461333  0        NA NA    NA     NA
0.008333333 0 0 0 0    21 21.11833 3.396333  0        NA NA    NA     NA
0.011111111 0 0 0 0    21 21.11800 3.359333  0        NA NA    NA     NA
0.013888889 0 0 0 0    21 21.12767 3.269333  0        NA NA    NA     NA
0.016666667 0 0 0 0    21 21.12933 3.225667  0        NA NA    NA     NA
```

Comment: add two small example data.frames to your question so it's reproducible and someone will hop on and help you.

Comment: Didn't try it, but in general what I would do if the column names are the same, is to just merge them together (using your method of choice, e.g. dplyr's `bind_rows()`). Either the data is sufficiently identified, because there's a column that tells you where it is from, or you need to add a column with that information. once you got your full data set you just need to set `aes(color=[your grouping variable])`

Comment: @minmat, try saveRDS instead of using RDA for those example files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dplyr bind rows did the trick in the end